# How do I get a Facebook app I've created to show up on a Facebook "Page"?

Tags: facebook

I have successfully created a Facebook application.  I have successfully added the application to my Facebook "Page".  After I do this, no link for the app shows up in the menu on the left.  This seems like something that should be simple to do, yet I can't find any documentation that is up-to-date.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the Page Tab settings in your application settings under Facebook Integration.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [developer page](http://www.facebook.com/developers/) where you get the list of your apps.

Click on the **more** link next to your app, and choose **Application profile**.

Once you are on the app profile, on the sidebar menu click on **Add to my page** and choose the page where you want to add the tab.

Note that you must have your app tab configured properly inside your app configuration in order to get this to work i.e. setting the correct domain and tab file.

If you are logged in as the page, I suggest you either creating a profile ID and log in as it, or the solution that @ifaour pointed out, although it will be difficult to find your app inside the search engine that FB provides.