# how to get facebook app to show up on my main fb page

Tags: facebook

I have a fb page, and I have a fb app (canvas). But no where on my page is there any info about my new app, such as a button or a tab. So if a person comes to my main fb page, they will be unable to find the app.

here is a deprecated answer using the old App Profile Page (which didn't work for me): [How do I get a Facebook app I've created to show up on a Facebook "Page"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045320/how-do-i-get-a-facebook-app-ive-created-to-show-up-on-a-facebook-page)

thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 0):

The page needs to be in the `app` category or the 'Go To App' / 'Play Game' link isn't rendered

{edit}
I may have misread your question, i thought you'd linked your app and page (i.e a page representing your app) but there was no 'go to app' link.

If you're talking about an app which is designed to be installed as a tab on another page, and you're not sure how to do that see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: hmmm ... when I go to Apps/my_app/Basic/Category pulldown, there is not an 'app' option. Currently I have it set to 'Games'.

But you are saying that the 'page ...'. What 'page' are you referring to please? Is the 'page' that you are referring to different from my app? ...different from my main page? ... thanks.

Comment: The app and the page are different things - it's not clear which you're asking about here - if it's the page you created for your app in the app settings, it needs to be in the 'App page' category - otherwise i'm not sure what you're asking about